# Customer grid is empty in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am developing a online store with Magento 2.2.2. I have to import customer from old site. The problem i am facing, in magento 2.2.2 customer grid is empty, even not a single grid title is showing (screenshot attached). [image]

I can add new customer successfully but new one also not showing in grid. If i try again with same email then showing customer already exists.

Solution I tried:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Any one can help me? Did I miss anything? Is there any way that I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After caching, re-indexing and trying few others things still i was unable to see customer in customer grid.

Then I have decided to drop following tables and import from fresh magento.

- **store**
- **store_group**
- **store_website**

I had a fresh magento 2.2.2 installed and i export above 3 tables and import in my dev version and It works for me. I can see all existing customer in customer grid.

I dont know what was the issue, i had no clue but after spending 2 days at last customer are back and that is enough for me now.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, check whether customer records exists in main table or not by using `select * from customer_entity limit 2;`

Then, check customer grid table if records are available or not, use `select * from customer_grid_flat limit 2;`

Before, reindexing it's better to check the state of the indexer by `select * from indexer_state;`

Then, update the status of re-index to make it invalid if the customer admin grid index status is valid or in working state by using below query

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status = 'working'
```

1st Set invalid From Database:

```
UPDATE `indexer_state` SET `status` = 'invalid' WHERE `indexer_state`.`indexer_id` ="indexer_id";
```

2nd run Cli Magento:

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Well, you've to update indexer_state because probably something went wrong during the re-index process, so because of that you need to reset the database entries.

Re-index doesn't work if the status of the index is not **invalid** (means re-index ignores the **valid** and **working** statuses.

Comment: Record exists in both table and index status all are valid but still customer not showing in grid.

Comment: Change the status to invalid first and then reindex again as mentioned above